# How to set up a NSLayoutConstraint in a NSScrollView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nsscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I am new to `NSLayoutConstraint`.

I want to manage the content of a `NSScrollView` programmatically. At the end, what I want to do is to create a subclass of `NSScrollView` with a method `- add:(NSView *)aView` that will add `aView` after the others and enlarge the `documentView` of the `NSScrollView` if necessary.

(all this for OSX) I guess it exists but can't find it, so if anyone knows where to find this, I am in ;) Here is a picture that can help you to understand :
[image]

My plan to do this is to use the `NSLayoutConstraint`s. The constraints will be :

- equal vertical space between `view 1`, `view 2`, etc.
- the `documentView` height should adapt to the sum of the heights of `view 1`, `view 2`, etc.
- some fixed vertical margins between the `documentView`and `view 1` and the last `view`.
- `view 1`, `view 2`, etc. are right-aligned

So, let us come to my question : I have started by just adding `view 1` (I will see it after for the rest). I did the following :

- `theScrollView` is my `NSScrollView` ;
- `newSubview` is the view I want to add ; with respect to the picture, it is `view 1`.

  ```
  theContainer = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, 0)] ;
  [theScrollView setDocumentView:theContainer] ;

  [newSubview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

  [theContainer addSubview:newSubview] ;

  NSLog(@"superview ? %@", [newSubview superview]) ;
  NSLog(@"view ? %@", newSubview) ;
  NSLog(@"NSScrollView ? %@", self) ;
  NSLog(@"NSScrollView content ? %@", self.contentView) ;

  NSArray * arrayOfConst1 ;
  arrayOfConst1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[newSubview]"
                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                         metrics:nil
                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(newSubview)];

  NSLog(@"First constraints : %@", arrayOfConst1) ;

  NSArray * arrayOfConst2 ;
  arrayOfConst2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[newSubview]"
                                                          options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(newSubview)];


  NSLog(@"Second constraints : %@", arrayOfConst2) ;

  [newSubview removeConstraints:[newSubview constraints]] ;
  [theContainer removeConstraints:[theContainer constraints]] ;
  [theContainer addConstraints:arrayOfConst1] ;
  [theContainer addConstraints:arrayOfConst2] ;

  NSLog(@"Frame of theContainer : %@", NSStringFromRect(theContainer.frame));
  ```

But, it doesn't work, the frame of `theContainer` remains `(0,0,0,0)`.

I am new to `NSLayoutConstraints` ; what I am missing ?

Comment: Are you reinventing the wheel? Why won't a view based NSTableView or NSCollectionView do what you want?

Comment: Yes you're right. It kinda seems it would be easier to create my own class than to manage with `NSTableView` or `NSCollectionView`. The thing is that the views that I add are complicated and need to be defined in their own xib. I will try !

Comment: Both `NSTableView` and `NSCollectionView` seemed to have been created to display a unique type of subview. Indeed, for `NSTableView`, the height of the cell is uniform. And, in `NSCollectionView`, there is only one prototype. So, I am not reinventing the wheel. I am looking for a more flexible tool.

Comment: NSTableView does allow different row heights.  You use the delegate 
`-tableView:heightOfRow:`.  And it also allows you to put any view in there. You simply add whatever view you want as a subview to an NSTableCellView.

NSCollectionView is even more flexible.  But more complex as a result. For a vertical list of views such as you want, NSTableView is almost certainly the way most Cocoa programmers would do it.

Comment: Thanks @SteveWaddicor. I'll go for it. It seems that concerning the views I want to add, I have to give a `Nib`. I would like to give a `NSView`...

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. All views are NSView subclasses. And you can always either define them in a xib (nib) or create them programatically.

Comment: I would like to tell to my `NSTableView` : "please, add this `NSView`" . So far, it seems that all I can tell is "please, add the `NSView` modeled on this `NSNib`" !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29929/discussion-between-steve-waddicor-and-colas)

Comment: @SteveWaddicor : actually, there was no problem to give back a `NSView` directly in the delegate method. Thanks for your help :)